# Rails: Database structure as models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activemodel

So this may sound a bit awkward, but I would like to have the database structure (tables, fkeys, columns) as a projection on Rails models e.g. the model

```
Table < ActiveModel
```

which would  respond to call like

```
Table.find_by_name('Account').columns.each
```

and so on. Is there any gem implementing something similar?

**Update:**

Basically there is a project that would query some remote open data sources (like world bank) and generate tables on the fly, and this is done by the database (yeah, sounds funny). The fact is that I have to show the the tables involved in a given query, distinguish which of them are local and which have just been generated, also draw the foreign keys and the columns.

Comment: Basically there is a project that would query some remote open data sources (like world bank) and generate tables on the fly, and this is done by the database (yeah, sounds funny). The fact is that I have to show the the tables involved in a given query, distinguish which of them are local and which have just been generated, also draw the foreign keys and the columns.

Comment: It can be done in some oldschool way with regular queries and stuff, but I prefer something more object oriented.

Comment: Ok... that should be part of the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea:

```
module Table

  def self.find_by_name(name)
    return const_get(name) if const_defined?(name)

    model = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base)
    model.set_table_name name.to_s.underscore.pluralize # sets the table
    const_set(name, model)

    model.column_names.each do |name|
      if name =~ /(\w+)_id$/
        model.belongs_to $1.to_sym
      end
    end

    model

  end

end
```

I don't really know if it'll work and what edge cases you'll run into. This solution is not for the faint-hearted and you should really know Ruby metaprogramming to make it work.

I hope this will give you some inspiration :)

Comment: that's quite a nice idea, thank you. I may do this if I cannot actually achieve what I mean.